# autoUpdater for electron mac app

Tags: macos, electron, auto-update

I am trying to set auto-updater for my electron mac app

In `main.js` I am using the following code for auto updater:

```
const electron = require('electron')
const autoUpdater = electron.autoUpdater;
const appVersion = require('./package.json').version;

autoUpdater.setFeedURL('https://my_server_address/test?v=' + appVersion);

autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();
```

I am using electron-packager for packaging my app.(without signing)

```
electron-packager . --platform=darwin --arch=x64
```

I am getting the error `Could not get code signature for running application`

What is the issue? Is signing required for auto updating? If no, how can I set up auto updater without signing the app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the app signing is required to set up autoUpdater.

After packaging the app. Signed the app using electron-osx-sign module, by running the following terminal command.

```
electron-osx-sign Test.app --identity 'Mac Developer: Arun (XXXXXXXXXX)'
```

Now auto update is working fine.